# homogeneous system with a given solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How can I find a linear homogeneous system whose solution is spanned by $(1,-2,0,0),(0,0,1,1), (-2,2,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1,0)$.

See if I am correct : The problem would be solved if I were able to find a linear transformation $T$ such that $ker(T)$ is spanned by those vectors, however, the vector above form a basis for $\mathbb R^4$, but we know that linear transformations take associate basis with basis. How can I proceed then? Since those vectors have to be associate with the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

The system 
$$0x_1+0x_2+0x_3+0x_4=0$$ has its solution space spanned by your (linearlly independent) vectors.